# Convert Node JS to ASP.NET C# for HMAC_SHA256 Hash

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to convert this Node JS code to ASP.NET C#:

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
/**
 * Validates a billing service webhook
 *
 * @param {string} req    Node request object, where 'req.body' is a Node
 *                        Buffer object containing the request body
 * @param {string} secret the secret string saved in the service App
 */
const isValidSignature = (req, secret) => {
  const fsSignature = req.headers['X-FS-Signature'];
  const computedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
    .update(req.body)
    .digest()
    .toString('base64');
  return fsSignature === computedSignature;
}
```

Here is my attempt in C#

```
    private bool CheckNotificationValidContextual(string varRequestHashValue, string varMessageBody) // #2047
    {

        // This involves a test of the webhook functionality using ngroks and Postman
        // to send values that were previously generated from a test webhook from billing service
        // to a local development copy of the seller application (running in Visual Studio)
        // where the inputs are:
        // varRequestHashValue = Request.Headers["X-Fs-Signature"];
        // varMessageBody = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        // get the local copy of the webhook secret key from the local web config file
        var AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256_Key = ConfigVal.AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256();

        // convert the local copy of the secret key to a byte array
        byte[] AMPTK_keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256_Key);

        // create a hash object with the local copy of the secret key
        var _hashObjectOfLocalKey = new HMACSHA256(AMPTK_keyBytes);

        // convert the input webhook message body to a byte array
        byte[] _messageBodyByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(varMessageBody);

        // create a hash byte array of the message body byte array
        // using the hash object based on the local copy of the webhook secret
        byte[] _computedMessageHashBytes = _hashObjectOfLocalKey.ComputeHash(_messageBodyByteArray);

        // convert the hash byte array of the message body to a string
        string _stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_computedMessageHashBytes, 0, _computedMessageHashBytes.Length);

            // remove dashes and convert to lowercase
            _stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes= BitConverter.ToString(_computedMessageHashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();


        // compare the string of the computed message body hash
        // to the received webhook secret hash value from Request.Headers["X-Fs-Signature"]
        if (_stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes == varRequestHashValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The C# code compiles and runs ok.

The result I'm looking for is:

prNdADI26M0ov5x6ZlMr2J2zzB8z2TJRBDy+8gjPttk=

What I'm getting from the C# code "_stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes"

is this:

f37cdae653e167e36c8ed17e44ffa456832dbb7dcec1d00dc1b44a1234965e73

I've checked the inputs carefully (could still be wrong).

Question:  have I translated the Node code properly to C#, and if not, how can I improve it?  Or what else might be off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your C# code for computing hash, in general looks ok, you used correct library and correct class `HMACSHA256` to calculate HMAC_SHA256 hash. The problem seems on the part that you were trying to convert the computed hash value to a base 64 string. You can use `Convert.ToBase64String` method to convert your byte array to base 64 string.

Here below you can find your updated C# code(I did minor improvements and updated the code to find `_stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes`).

I tested the hash results generated from **node.js** and **C#**, now they are both generating the same hash result:

```
    private bool CheckNotificationValidContextual(string varRequestHashValue, string varMessageBody) // #2047
    {
        // This involves a test of the webhook functionality using ngroks and Postman
        // to send values that were previously generated from a test webhook from billing service
        // to a local development copy of the seller application (running in Visual Studio)
        // where the inputs are:
        // varRequestHashValue = Request.Headers["X-Fs-Signature"];
        // varMessageBody = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        // get the local copy of the webhook secret key from the local web config file
        var AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256_Key = ConfigVal.AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256();

        // convert the local copy of the secret key to a byte array
        var AMPTK_keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AMPTK_FSP_HMAC_SHA256_Key);

        // create a hash object with the local copy of the secret key
        using (var _hashObjectOfLocalKey = new HMACSHA256(AMPTK_keyBytes))
        {
            // convert the input webhook message body to a byte array
            var _messageBodyByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(varMessageBody);

            // create a hash byte array of the message body byte array
            // using the hash object based on the local copy of the webhook secret
            var _computedMessageHashBytes = _hashObjectOfLocalKey.ComputeHash(_messageBodyByteArray);

            var _stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(_computedMessageHashBytes);

            // compare the string of the computed message body hash
            // to the received webhook secret hash value from Request.Headers["X-Fs-Signature"]
            return _stringOfComputedMessageHashBytes == varRequestHashValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works slick. I appreciate the guidance. Thanks**n.